# Calculate the probability of occurrence of events in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, probability, transition, crosstab

I have a matrix as following that shows the actions and current states and next states in a Markov model.

```
                   Action        State..t.       state.t.1.
1  Use Experinced supplier within becnhamrk within becnhamrk
2  Use Experinced supplier within becnhamrk within becnhamrk
3  Use Experinced supplier out of Benchmark out of Benchmark
4 Use The nearest Supplier within becnhamrk within becnhamrk
5 Use The nearest Supplier out of Benchmark out of Benchmark
6 Use The nearest Supplier out of Benchmark out of Benchmark
```

Then I want to calculate the probability of occurrence of events and replace it with the default probability of following matrix(p):

```
  state<-c("within becnhamrk","out of Benchmark")
     action<-c("Use Experinced supplier","Use The nearest Supplier")
    p<-array(0,c(length(state),length(state),length(action)))
    colnames(p)=state
    rownames(p)=state
    # transition probability matrix based on the action that we have choosen
    for(i in 1:length(action)){
      p[,,i]<-matrix(0, nrow=length(state), ncol=length(state), byrow=TRUE)
    }
```

When I execute function of ftable(), it gives me the frequency table but I want to find the probability of going from state(t) to state(t+1) when I take action 1 or action 2. How can I populate the below matrix with the probability value which will be calculated from the first table.

```
 , , 1

                 within becnhamrk out of Benchmark
within becnhamrk                0                0
out of Benchmark                0                0

, , 2

                 within becnhamrk out of Benchmark
within becnhamrk                0                0
out of Benchmark                0                0
```

Comment: Pictures of data are bad. Instead, post the results of `dput(yourData)`. If it's too big, pick a representative subset, say with `head(yourData, 10)`.

Comment: Sure ,I have updated my Question, can you please look at it again.